# Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; Running or Debugging in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries

On Ubuntu, I have a C++ app in Eclipse. The application compiles fine and I can run the app from the command line.

But when I try to debug it or run it with Eclipse, the **error :**

`"Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"` is thrown on a shared library.

I've set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my bashrc file and also set an LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in both the Run Configuration and Debug Configuration to :

> /home/behlingb/Documents/api_libs/FileGDB_API/lib

What else am I missing here to get Eclipse to run this?

**UPDATE**

There is only one shared object file this application requires, and that file is from a 3rd party API download. I just found that if I place the shared object inside the directory the executable is in, it will debug in Eclipse. Is there a way to specify a different directory so I dont have to copy the file for every project?

Comment: I think you're on the right track with setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Run Configuration.  Have you checked to make sure that you're running it using that run configuration? In LiClipse, if you click on the little, downwards, grey arrow besides the big, green-circled, rightwards, white arrow, you can choose which run configuration to use.

Comment: I found the Eclipse CDT (neon.3) isn't very "stable".  Sometimes, ctrl+arrow doesn't work.  Closing the window fixes it.  Sometimes, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't appended what I asked for.  Restarting fixes it.

Answer (score 21):

I'm using the Kepler version of Eclipse.

1. In Eclipse click on Run then Debug Configurations
2. Click on the Environment Tab
3. Click on New
4. Add LD_LIBRARY_PATH and set its value to the directory containing the library
5. restart Eclipse

Answer (score 4):

If you have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it doesn't work. Close Eclipes and run it from command terminal. I accidentally found that this could make it work. Not sure about the reason, but probably have something to do with Eclipes initialization.

Comment: By the way, I am using Luna version of Eclipes

Comment: I'm guessing this is because terminal sources ~/.bashrc upon launch, and you had `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in this file.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `strace` utility (and then `grep` for `open` and/or `stat` calls) to get list of .so files required to run smth, then use `locate` (or find among packages) to find out the actual placement of required lib

Answer (score 3):

According to what @zuafi suggested , you do not have to grep for the libraries and `locate' to find them.

Instead save strace's output to a file:

```
strace -o my_output_file.txt /path/to/my_executable_file
```

then open the file, where you can see

```
open("/a/path/to/some/library.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

scroll down those lines until you hit

```
open("/real/path/to/some/library.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 (any value here)
```

this means before finding `/real/path/to/some/library.so` there have been several trials to find `library.so` in different paths. but finally the library has been found in `/real/path/to/some/`.

Just copy and paste this into your Eclipse!

Answer (score 2):

This is valid with Eclipse Kepler (I have not looked into older versions).
To enable the debugger to load your shared libraries, trying to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH will fail. However the CDT plugin provides a *Shared Libraries* list for this purpose

> ***Run*** menu -> ***Debug Configurations ...***

then in the configuration dialog

> ***C/C++ Application*** -> *your project* -> ***Debugger*** tab -> ***Shared Libraries*** tab

[image: The Kepler dialog for adding debug shared libraries]

Comment: This really seems like it should be the correct answer. I've tried it on Mars and it doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: agree with Menace, for CDT on Luna this does not seem to work, only adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to have the desired effect as described by monzie