# Linking shared object library to Eclipse (Oxygen)

Tags: c++, eclipse, .so

I have a shared object library (.so file) that was created from command line (not in Eclipse). I want to use it in my C++ project. I have set up library directory and library name in `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross G++ Linker -> Libraries` properly. My project compiles correctly and produces the binary. But when I try to run it, it gives me the following error.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libsharedObjectLibrary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

I have library directory set up correctly. What else is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting up LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Debug configurations -> Environment. Described at [Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; Running or Debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448343/cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-running-or-debugging)