# Eclipse can't find library for compiled executable

Tags: python, eclipse

In Eclipse 4.10.0 I'm working on a Python script that calls a C++/CUDA executable (that I wrote and compiled myself too with Nsight) at one point via `subprocess.call()`. This causes an error message: `error while loading shared libraries: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I had the same problem when running the file in an Ubuntu terminal until I updated ~/.bashrc with: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but how do I apply that in Eclipse? I tried adding both `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so.10.0` and `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcufft.so.10.0` to the Eclipse project under Project properties->Resource->Linked Resources->Path Variables, but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19977247/5522601): In the Python project's run configuration, go to the Environment tab and add the path variable (in my case `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) with the value of the directory of the library (in my case `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`).